# Grouped Weighted Average in Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, average, weighted

I am trying to have a weighted average fee % of sales for each Client/Product/City combo from this data. I don't need the level of detail of sub product.

My data looks like this:

```
+--------+---------+-------+--------------+-------+----------------+
| Client | Product | City  | Sub Product  | Sales | Fee % of Sales |
+--------+---------+-------+--------------+-------+----------------+
| a      | b       | b     | c            |  1000 | 1%             |
| a      | b       | b     | d            |  2000 | 2%             |
| c      | c       | b     | c            |  3000 | 3%             |
| d      | c       | b     | c            |  4000 | 4%             |
+--------+---------+-------+--------------+-------+----------------+
```

I want to calculate the weighted average Fee % charged for each Client & Product combo. i.e. For Client `'a'`, Product `'b'`, City `'b'`: the fee% of sales would be `(1,000/3,000)*1% + (2,000/3000 * 2%)`

After I do this I will have another query that takes only the Client, Product,City Sales and new Weighted average field from the last query. I need another query because I will be using the results as part of a larger query.

Comment: we will not resolve your homework. please give us proof of your tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would have been easier done using window function, but since you are using ms-access... You can compute the sales subtotals per client/product/city in a subquery, and then `JOIN` in with the original table:

```
SELECT 
    t.client, t.product, t.city, SUM(t.sales * t.fee / t1.sales) res
FROM 
    mytable t
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT client, product, city, SUM(sales) sales
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY client, product, city
    ) t1 
        ON  t1.client = t.client
        AND t1.product = t.product
        AND t1.city = t.city
GROUP BY t.client, t.product, t.city
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sHGLfXQ34XUjjFMKdWwhuC/1)** with your sample data returns:

```
| client | product | city | res                             |
| ------ | ------- | ---- | ------------------------------- |
| a      | b       | b    | 0.016666666294137638            |
| c      | c       | b    | 0.029999999329447746            |
| d      | c       | b    | 0.03999999910593033             |
```

Comment: Thank ya! Took me a while to decipher since some of the syntax in your code did not work but it works now!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the total sales & fee values as part of a subquery, then perform the division with the resulting values, e.g.:

```sql
select 
    q.client, 
    q.product, 
    q.city, 
    q.fee/q.totalsales as weightedfee
from
(
    select 
        t.client, 
        t.product, 
        t.city,
        sum(t.sales) as totalsales,
        sum(t.sales*t.[fee % of sales]) as fee
    from yourtable t
    group by t.client, t.product, t.city
) q
```

Change `yourtable` to suit your table name.